# How to add option of add to cart for simple products on bundle product page?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, bundle

I have got a situation where I need to place a button of add to cart for every simple product on bundle product page. So that customer can order that particular simple item of bundle product individually.

Any one have any guess how should i do that.

Please reply

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a helper for that: [`Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::getAddUrl()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Cart.php#L52).

In your child products loop you need only feed that method the child product instance and it will render the proper URL. You can adjust with quantity, etc via JavaScript.